# Сделать меню для готовой программы

Tags: java, menu

Лабораторная работа: Нужно взять код из предыдущей лабораторной, но переобразовать его таким образом, чтобы выбор действия производился из консоли:

```
1. Ввод данных
2. Вывод данных
3. Провести расчет
4. Вывод результата
5. Завершить программу
```

Сама программа берет текст, и удаляет слово по заданной длинне.

```
        // initialize scanner for read data from console
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // getting entered text
        String text = scanner.nextLine();
        // getting word length
        int wlength = scanner.nextInt(); 
        
        // splitting text for manipulating with it in loop
        String[] sarr = text.split(" "); 
        // initializing StringBuffer as sb
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < sarr.length; i++) {
            // getting first letter of each word during loop as fl
            char fl = sarr[i].charAt(0); 
            
            // check if the word length is NOT equal with entered length,
            // so adding words to StringBuffer that don't need to be deleted
            if (!((sarr[i].length() % wlength == 0) && ((fl != 'a') && (fl != 'e') && (fl != 'i') && (fl != 'o') && (fl != 'u') && (fl != 'y'))))
                sb.append(sarr[i]).append(" ");
        }
        
        // converting array to string and removing whitespaces from ends
        String output = sb.toString().trim();
        
        System.out.println(output + " \n\n");
```

Также обязательным пунктом - поддержка флагов -h и -d. То есть:

Если при флаге **-h** или **-help** отображается информация об авторе и т.д., то при флаге
**-d** или **-debug**, в процессе работы отображаются дополнительные данные, которые облегчают сборку, временные данные и т д.

**Проблема:** Как при помощи switch это все обсутроить? Была идея это сделать при помощи if следующим образом:

```
if (choice == '1') {
            if (args[2] == "-h" || args[2] == "help") {
                System.out.println("Help 1:\nThis command is set you to enter text and length\n");
            }
            
            else if(args[2] == "-d" || args[2] == "debug") {
            }
        }
```

Полный код моей попытки:

```
package Lab04;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String text;
        int length;
        
        System.out.println("=============================");
        System.out.println("|      MENU SELECTION       |");
        System.out.println("=============================");
        System.out.println("| Options:                  |");
        System.out.println("|   1. Entering data        |");
        System.out.println("|   2. Review data          |");
        System.out.println("|   3. Execute calculations |");
        System.out.println("|   4. Outputting result    |");
        System.out.println("|   5. Exit                 |");
        System.out.println("=============================");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: "); 
        choice = scanner.nextInt(); 
        
        /*
        if (choice == '1') {
            if (args[2] == "-h" || args[2] == "help") {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            
            else if(args[2] == "-d" || args[2] == "debug") {
                System.out.println("");
                // code here
            }
            
            else 
                System.out.println("You've entered 1:\nEntering data: ");
                
            text = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        */
        
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            text = scanner.nextLine();
            break;
        
        case 2:
            System.out.println(text);
            break;
            
        default:
            System.out.println("There is no such option\n");
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

В первом кейсе идет ввод с клавиатуры текста, но во втором кейсе подчеркивается **text** как неинициализированная переменная

Главная проблема в том, что при вводе данных в кейсе, данные в кейсе и остаются, и остальной код эти данные не видит

Answer (score 0):

Думаю загвоздка в областях видимости переменных. Вам нужно объявить переменные, которые нужны вам за пределами кейсов, раньше switch.
Выглядет это примерно так:

```
 int data = 0; //переменная которая нужна за пределами switch-case
 String switcher=""; //ключ, введенный с консоли
    
        switch (switcher) {
            case ("a"): { //если введено a 
                data = 1;
            }
            case ("b"): { //если введено b
                data = 42;
            }
        }
  System.out.println(data) //выведется значение data, присвоенное внутри case
```

Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте полный код чтобы можно было сказать наверняка

UPD. Инициализируйте строковую переменную пустой строкой сразу при объявлении `String string = ""` если не присваиваете ей значение вскоре после объявления. Это поможет избежать ошибки обращения к неиниализированной строке

Comment: Вопрос дополнил. Я пробовал с объявлением переменной в самом верху программы, но это не помогло

Comment: Sting перед использованием нужно инициализировать пустой строкой (Strint text=""). После этого я запустил у себя ваш код. Переменная text перезаписывается в case и остается доступна за его пределами.

Comment: Приведенный вами код - это весь проект?

Comment: да, приведенный код это и есть весь "проект"

Answer (score 0):

Решил, и вопрос более неактуален.

**Решение:**

```
    package Lab04;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String text = "";
        int length = 0;
        String output = "";
        
        String separator = "-";
        
        while(true) {
            
            System.out.println("=============================");
            System.out.println("|      MENU SELECTION       |");
            System.out.println("=============================");
            System.out.println("| Options:                  |");
            System.out.println("|   1. Entering data        |");
            System.out.println("|   2. Review data          |");
            System.out.println("|   3. Execute calculations |");
            System.out.println("|   4. Outputting result    |");
            System.out.println("|   5. Exit                 |");
            System.out.println("=============================");
            System.out.println("Enter your choice: "); 
            choice = scanner.nextInt(); 
            
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Chosen variant: 1");
                if (args.length != 0) {
                    if (args.length == 2) {
                        if (    (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("-h")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("help")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("-d")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("-d"))
                            ) {
                            System.out.println("\n================================");
                            System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                            System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                            System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                            System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (args.length == 1) {
                        if (args[0].equals("-h") || args[0].equals("help")) {
                        System.out.println("\n================================");
                        System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                        System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                        System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                        System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (args[0].equals("-h") == false && args[0].equals("help") == false && args[0].equals("-d") == false && args[0].equals("debug") == false) 
                        System.out.println("No such option");
                }
                
                scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    
                System.out.println("\n------------------\nEnter text:");
                text = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\n------------------\nEnter word length: ");
                length = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("------------------\n");
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Chosen variant: 2");
                
                if (args.length != 0) {
                    if (args.length == 2) {
                        if (    (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("-h")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("help")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("-d")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("-d"))
                            ) {
                            System.out.println("\n================================");
                            System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                            System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                            System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                            System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (args.length == 1) {
                        if (args[0].equals("-h") || args[0].equals("help")) {
                        System.out.println("\n================================");
                        System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                        System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                        System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                        System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (!args[0].equals("-h") && !args[0].equals("help") && !args[0].equals("-d") && !args[0].equals("debug")) 
                        System.out.println("No such option!");
                }
                
                System.out.println("\n" + separator.repeat(14 + text.length()) + "\nEntered text: " + text);
                System.out.println("\n" + separator.repeat(17) + "\nEntered length: " + length);
                System.out.println(separator.repeat(17) + "\n");
                
                break;
                
            case 3:
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("\n----------------------------\nThere is no text to work out\n----------------------------\n");
                    break;
                }
                
                System.out.println("Chosen variant: 3");
                
                if (args.length != 0) {
                    if (args.length == 2) {
                        if (    (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("-h")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("help")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("-d")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("-d"))
                            ) {
                            System.out.println("\n================================");
                            System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                            System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                            System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                            System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (args.length == 1) {
                        if (args[0].equals("-h") || args[0].equals("help")) {
                        System.out.println("\n================================");
                        System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                        System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                        System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                        System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (args[0].equals("-d") || args[0].equals("debug")) {
                        String[] sarr = text.split(" "); 
                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < sarr.length; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Iter" + i + ": " + sarr[i] + " ");
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println("Splitted string: " + Arrays.toString(sarr) + "\n");
                        
                        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < sarr.length; i++) {
                            char fl = sarr[i].charAt(0);
                            System.out.println("First letter on iter " + i + ": " + fl);
                            
                            if (!((sarr[i].length() % length == 0) && ((fl != 'a') && (fl != 'e') && (fl != 'i') && (fl != 'o') && (fl != 'u') && (fl != 'y'))))
                                sb.append(sarr[i]).append(" ");
                            
                            System.out.println("Appending word to an array with whitespace on iter. " + i + ": " + sarr[i] + "\n");
                            System.out.println("Temp value of array: " + Arrays.toString(sarr));
                        }
                        
                        output = sb.toString().trim();
                        System.out.println("\nTrimmed string for output: " + output);
                    }
                    
                    if (args[0].equals("-h") == false && args[0].equals("help") == false && args[0].equals("-d") == false && args[0].equals("debug") == false) 
                        System.out.println("No such option");
                }
                
                String[] sarr = text.split(" "); 
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
                
                for (int i = 0; i < sarr.length; i++) {
                    char fl = sarr[i].charAt(0); 
                    
                    if (!((sarr[i].length() % length == 0) && ((fl != 'a') && (fl != 'e') && (fl != 'i') && (fl != 'o') && (fl != 'u') && (fl != 'y'))))
                        sb.append(sarr[i]).append(" ");
                }
                
                output = sb.toString().trim();
                
                System.out.println("\n" + separator.repeat(33) + "\nCalculations are done successful!\n" + separator.repeat(33) + "\n");
                
                break;
                
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Chosen variant: 4");
                
                if (args.length != 0) {
                    if (args.length == 2) {
                        if (    (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("-h")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-d") && args[1].equals("help")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("help") && args[1].equals("-d")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("debug")) ||
                                (args[0].equals("-h") && args[1].equals("-d"))
                            ) {
                            System.out.println("\n================================");
                            System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                            System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                            System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                            System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (args.length == 1) {
                        if (args[0].equals("-h") || args[0].equals("help")) {
                        System.out.println("\n================================");
                        System.out.println("|   Author:                      |");
                        System.out.println("|   Year:                        |");
                        System.out.println("|   Group:                       |");
                        System.out.println("==================================\n");
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (args[0].equals("-h") == false && args[0].equals("help") == false && args[0].equals("-d") == false && args[0].equals("debug") == false) 
                        System.out.println("No such option");
                }
                
                if (output.length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println(""
                            + "\n---------------------------\nThere is no text for output\n---------------------------\n");
                    break;
                }
                
                System.out.println("\n" + separator.repeat(8 + output.length()) + "\nResult: " + output + "\n" + separator.repeat(8 + output.length()) + "\n");
                
                break;
                
            case 5:
                System.out.println("\n----------\nExiting...\n----------\n");
                
                System.exit(0);
                
            default:
                System.out.println("There is no such option\n");
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```